# Print BackSlash and Double Quotes ('\"') in Haskell

Tags: haskell, char, escaping, special-characters, double-quotes

My question would be that I want to print out the following Char in Haskell

```
'\"'
```

And in exactly this form. Because the escape character makes it possible to print out the double quotes, my output is the following now.

```
'"'
```

But this is not good for my case. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escaping everything works:

```
> putStrLn "\'\\\"\'"
'\"'
```

Update: as [David Fletcher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4168972/david-fletcher) mentions in the comments, there's actually no need to escape the single quotes here.

Comment: There's no need to escape single quotes inside a double-quoted string.

Comment: @DavidFletcher you're right. but there's no harm, is there. :) that's just what I tried and it worked. I'll edit now. thanks! :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why did you have to triple backslash before the double quotes ? Isn't sufficient to escape the backslash in other to print one ? I am asking since I am using double backslashes and I have a parse error.